# CD4053B Supply Voltage Ambigious in Datasheet

Tags: datasheet, cd4053

I'm designing an analog voltage switcher based on the CD4053 and +-15V rails. By accident, I ordered the HEF4053 which clearly states that Vdd-Vee may not exceed 18V.

Now I'm looking at the [TI CD4053B datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4051b.pdf?ts=1592330448520) where it states:

Supply Voltage (V+ to V-, Voltages Referenced to VSS Terminal): Max 20V.

The question is: Can I run a CD4053 from Vee=-15V and Vdd=15V?

Comment: I don't think so I think you can go with +10,-10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference: **Motorola CMOS LOGIC DATA** DL131 Rev 2.

VDD > VSS > VEE
maximum between VDD and VEE is -0.5V to +18V. VSS is somewhere in-between.

"\$V_{DD}\$ voltage is the logic high voltage, the \$V_{SS}\$ voltage is logic low. For example, \$V_{DD} = 5V\$ = logic high at the control inputs. \$V_{SS} = GND = 0V\$ = logic low.
The maximum analog signal level is determined by \$V_{DD}\$ and \$V_{EE}\$. The \$V_{DD}\$ voltage determines the maximum recommended peak above \$V_{SS}\$. The \$V_{EE}\$ voltage determines the maximum swing below \$V_{SS}\$.
[...]

If voltage transients above \$V_{DD}\$ and/or below \$V_{EE}\$ are anticipated on the analog channels, external diodes are recommended [...] small signal types able to absorb the maximum anticipated current surges during clipping."

Perhaps Texas Instruments allows a few more volts headroom than other manufacturers, but a difference of 30V between VDD and VEE is outside spec.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. The absolute maximum **total** voltage across the chip is 18V or 20V (15V nominal). You would be applying 30V.